# Using zref return value as input for counter

Tags: counters, zref, calc

I am trying to create a new counter, which is counting the page numbers to store them and reuse them later. I always remove the 3 pages, which are not numbered at the beginning of the document and I would then just add this value of `\CurrPage` to my counter. 
So far I've managed to extract the page number from Roman using `zref`, but this value can't be added to my counter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize = 12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}
% Page Numbering Roman
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[abspage,user,lastpage]{zref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\CurrPage}{%
\zlabel{page.num} 
\number\numexpr
\zref@extract{page.num}{abspage}%
-3%
\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Counter Definition Framework
\newcounter{Page.Num.Framework}
\lipsum[1-25]

Current Page Num: {\CurrPage}

%\addtocounter{Page.Num.Framework}{\CurrPage}

\end{document}
```

If uncommented, the `\addtocounter` command returns the error:

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \addtocounter{Page.Num.Framework}{\CurrPage}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems: A general one and one of using `calc`.

First the general one: `\CurrPage` expands to first setting a label and next using the value generated by the label. Setting the label is not a number, so adding `\zlabel{…}` to a counter always fails. This problem could be solved by a simple change of `\CurrPage`:

```
\newcommand*{\CurrPage}{%
  \number\numexpr
  \zref@extract{page.num}{abspage}%
  -3%
  \relax
  \zlabel{page.num}%
}
```

Now, `\CurrPage` first results in a number an then in generation of a label. With this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize = 12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}
% Page Numbering Roman
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[abspage,user,lastpage]{zref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\CurrPage}{%
  \number\numexpr
  \zref@extract{page.num}{abspage}%
  -3%
  \relax
  \zlabel{page.num}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Counter Definition Framework
\newcounter{Page.Num.Framework}
\lipsum[1-25]

Current Page Num: {\CurrPage}

Before: \arabic{Page.Num.Framework}
\addtocounter{Page.Num.Framework}{\CurrPage}
After: \arabic{Page.Num.Framework}

\end{document}
```

works (but is still ugly).

The special problem of using `calc` is, that `calc` allows calculations in `\addtocounter` and with that package the argument of `\addtocounter` must be a numeric expression without commands that do not expand to numbers. So

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize = 12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}
% Page Numbering Roman
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[abspage,user,lastpage]{zref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\CurrPage}{%
  \number\numexpr
  \zref@extract{page.num}{abspage}%
  -3%
  \relax
  \zlabel{page.num}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Counter Definition Framework
\newcounter{Page.Num.Framework}
\lipsum[1-25]

Current Page Num: {\CurrPage}

Before: \arabic{Page.Num.Framework}
\addtocounter{Page.Num.Framework}{\CurrPage}
After: \arabic{Page.Num.Framework}

\end{document}
```

still fails and you have to split of `\CurrPage` in a label generation and label usage:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize = 12pt,headsepline]{scrartcl}
% Page Numbering Roman
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[abspage,user,lastpage]{zref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\StoreCurrPage}{\zlabel{page.num}}
\newcommand*{\UseCurrPage}{%
  \numexpr
  \zref@extract{page.num}{abspage}%
  -3%
  \relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Counter Definition Framework
\newcounter{Page.Num.Framework}
\lipsum[1-25]

Before: \arabic{Page.Num.Framework}
\StoreCurrPage\addtocounter{Page.Num.Framework}{\UseCurrPage}
After: \arabic{Page.Num.Framework}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, well I just copy&pasted a somehow "working" version, so I was not aware of the underlying concepts.